# Can't execute shell script commands in sandboxed cocoa app

Tags: macos, shell, cocoa, nstask, appstore-sandbox

I developed a cocoa application that builds, archives and creates iOS application files. Now I want to release it to Mac App Store. My app runs correctly, but not in sandbox mode. App structure is as following:

```
MyApp.app
|_Contents
  |_Resources
    |_BuildTask.command
```

1. The first thing I've done is to get permission to execute "BuildTask.command".

   ```
    NSTask *permissionTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    permissionTask.launchPath = @"/bin/bash";
    permissionTask.arguments = @[@"-c", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chmod +x %@", pathToBuildTask], @"run"];
    [permissionTask launch];
    [permissionTask waitUntilExit];
   ```

Otherwise, BuildTask produces an error:

```
Problem Running Task: launch path not accessible
```

2. After executing the permission task, I execute my BuildTask.command file  with NSTask that includes xcodebuild commands in it.

   ```
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BuildTask" ofType:@"command"]];
    task.launchPath = path;
    task.arguments = scriptArguments;
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];
   ```

Everything is OK when App Sandbox is off in Capabilities. When I enable App Sandbox for Mac App Store, permission task gives error:

```
chmod: Unable to change file mode on .../MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/BuildTask.command: Operation not permitted
```

When I execute chmod on BuildTask.command manually, defaults write commands and xcodebuild commands in BuildTask.command give errors like:

```
defaults[2264:70400] Could not write domain .../SampleApp/SampleApp/SampleApp-Info.plist; exiting

xcodebuild[2410] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamCreate: _FSEventStreamCreate: ERROR: watch_path() failed for '/'
xcodebuild[2410] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamCopyPathsBeingWatched(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'

../MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/BuildTask.command: line 65:  2410 Segmentation fault: 11  xcodebuild -scheme "${SCHEME}" clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${SIGNING_IDENTITY}" "${BUILD_ARGUMENT}" "${WORKSPACE_OR_PROJECT}"
```

So, do I have any chance to release this tool to Mac App Store?

Any help would really appreciated.

Comment: In a sandboxed application you can't change any file within the application bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not what you want to hear:

> 1. The first thing I've done is to get permission to execute "BuildTask.command".

You have two problems here. First if you wish to change the permissions on a file from within an app you should be using framework or system calls to do so directly, not calling `NSTask` to execute a shell which in turn executes a command which calls those framework or system calls...

Second you should not be trying to change the contents of your application bundle from within the application. If you need a file in your application bundle to have execute permission then set it when you build the app. You can do that with a build phase in Xcode.

> So, have I any chance to release this tool to Mac App Store?

Little or none.

Xcode itself is not a sandboxed application and the error messages you are getting indicate that it is trying to do operations which violate the sandbox it has inherited from your app.

HTH

Comment: I changed the permission of the build script as you've mentioned. It was OK but I probably can't upload this tool to Mac App Store because of xcodebuild errors.